# T-SQL - 3 month moving sum - preceding null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016. I have the following data table (sample)

```
Target Date Total
-----------------
2018-01-24  1
2018-02-28  1
2018-03-02  1
2018-03-08  1
2018-03-15  1
2018-03-30  1
2018-04-16  1
2018-04-18  1
2018-04-30  1
```

I would like to get to get a 3 month moving sum (grouping is by month):

```
  Target Date   Total_Sum
  -----------------------
  2018-01-01      1
  2018-02-01      2
  2018-03-01      6
  2018-04-01      8
```

Comment: Do you have records for all consecutive months? If you need a sum why did you try max?

Comment: How is that output a 3 month sum?

Comment: I don't get how you calculated desired output. Anyway **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ccb667319c4ad035cec2f02c384605d6)**

Comment: I agree with @paparazzo that's not a 3month sum. I would, for example, expect the value `17` or `9` for April (depends if you meant that month and the 2 prior, or the 3 prior months). Certainly not `8` for April, and I've no idea how March has a value of `6`. Can you explain your logic please?

Comment: Sorry, let me revise this. I have a running total, I shall post the raw data

Comment: I still don't understand how you get the values you require.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this issue, please see above revised post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this should get the answer you want. Firstly you need to total the value your months, then you can do a running total for the last 3 months:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (TargetDate date, Total int);
GO

INSERT INTO SampleTable
VALUES ('20180124', 1),
       ('20180228', 1),
       ('20180302', 1),
       ('20180308', 1),
       ('20180315', 1),
       ('20180330', 1),
       ('20180416', 1),
       ('20180418', 1),
       ('20180430', 1);
GO

SELECT *
FROM SampleTable;
GO
WITH Months AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TargetDate),0) AS TargetMonth, SUM(Total) AS MonthTotal
    FROM SampleTable
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TargetDate),0))
SELECT TargetMonth,
       SUM(MonthTotal) OVER (ORDER BY TargetMonth ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Last3Months
FROM Months;

GO
DROP TABLE SampleTable;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try the below code

```
;WITH CTE(TargetDate,Total)
AS
(
SELECT '2018-01-24', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-02-28', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-02', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-08', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-15', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-30', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-04-16', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-04-18', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-04-30', 1
)
SELECT STUFF(TargetDate,9,2,'01') AS TargetDate
      ,Total_Sum
FROM
(
    SELECT TargetDate,Total_Sum 
       ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Total_Sum ORDER BY TargetDate) AS Seq
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  TargetDate
                ,SUM(Total )OVER(ORDER BY MONTH(TargetDate) ) AS Total_Sum
        FROM CTE
    )dt
)fnl 
WHERE Seq=1
```

Result

```
TargetDate  Total_Sum
---------------------
2018-01-01      1
2018-02-01      2
2018-03-01      6
2018-04-01      9
```

Comment: Thank you Sireenu, this calculates a running total that is also useful for me. Will give it a try! Regards.

Comment: Happy to help bro